# Error when trying to map a recursive relation

Tags: java, jpa, recursion

I'm trying to map a recursive relation using JPA. I don't know why I'm getting some errors on the @OneToMany line.
Here is a code sample:

```
@Entity
public class RecursiveType implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2459343636539882731L;

    @Id
    public int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="rec1", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST) //here is where I get the errors
    public RecursiveType rec1;
    public Map<String, Map<RecursiveType, List<Map<RecursiveType, List<InnerTypes>>>>> rec2;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And the line of `persistence.xml` file

```
    <class>pt.ptinovacao.persistencetester.model.RecursiveType</class>
```

I've had several errors like: "Target entity is not defined" and "The attribute type for a collection mapping must be java.util.Collection…"
Why does this happen?

Comment: `Map<String, Map<RecursiveType, List<Map<RecursiveType, List<InnerTypes>>>>>` Whoa ... what's that?

Comment: I really can't tell, this isn't my code, so I don't know why they need that... I'm just trying to fix the errors lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it, I just changed the annotations and the relation type

```
@Entity
public class RecursiveType implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2459343636539882731L;

    @Id
    public int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="REC1_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
    public RecursiveType rec1;    
    public Map<String, Map<RecursiveType, List<Map<RecursiveType, List<InnerTypes>>>>> rec2; //I really don't need to try and map this xD

    //getters and setters
}
```